# For any non-singular square matrix A, is A + A' a Positive Definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I have to prove or disprove this statement. I am not sure how to do it. I think we cannot be certain that it will be positive definite, but how to state the proof?

Comment: Let $A = -I$, so $A+A' = -2I$.

Comment: The statement that you're dealing with is $A + A'$ is PSD for every $A$.  To prove that the statement is **not** true, all you need to show is the opposite of this statement, i.e. that there **exists** an $A$ for which $A + A'$ is not PSD.  In other words, all you need here is an example.

Comment: what's $A'$ ?i'm unfamiliar with this notation.

Comment: @infinity A' means the transpose of A. I've seen this notation being used quite frequently.

Comment: @MollieVX thanks. im used to $A^T$.

Comment: A positive (semi)definite matrix can never have negatives on the diagonal (why?)... if $A$ has negatives on the diagonal, then so does $A^T$ and so does $A+A^T$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is not true.  For example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}.
$$